# Fullscreen Chart.js while keeping the chart quality

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I have chart.js. It looks good when it is with a smaller size, but I have implemented also a fullscreen option to the chart.

It opens as expected, but the quality of the chart when on fullscreen is poor as it just resizes the small map to fullscreen.

Any idea how to call the chart again in a bigger size when opening on fullscreen?

This is the JS I am using to open the fullscreen

```
function toggleFullscreen(elem) {
  var elem = document.getElementById("canvas");
  if (!document.fullscreenElement && !document.mozFullScreenElement &&
  !document.webkitFullscreenElement && !document.msFullscreenElement) {
    if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
      elem.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) {
      elem.msRequestFullscreen();
    } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
      elem.webkitRequestFullscreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
    }
  } else {
    if (document.exitFullscreen) {
      document.exitFullscreen();
    } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
      document.msExitFullscreen();
    } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
      document.mozCancelFullScreen();
    } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
      document.webkitExitFullscreen();
    }
  }
}

document.getElementById('fs-doc-button').addEventListener('click', function () {
  toggleFullscreen('#canvas');
});

document.getElementById('W').addEventListener('click', function () {
  toggleFullscreen(this);
});
```

And this is the canvas holding the chart

```
<div class="chart-container">
<canvas id='canvas'  style='background-color:white;width: 100%;'></canvas>
</div>
```

And this it the button I am opening it with

```
<button id='fs-doc-button'>Fullscreen</button>
```

The only thing I can think is creating a new hidden canvas with bigger chart size and opening it fullscreen, but sounds quite dirty to me:)

So, wondering I can combine somehow the two ideas.